# How to print a blank space in vb6

Tags: vb6

So i want the printer to print a blank space. So in the paper it will look like this

```
Hello World

`above is the blank space
```

then it will print with the blank space, but in my case it just print like this:

```
Hello World
```

Here is my code:

```
Printer.CurrentX = 0
Printer.CurrentY = 0
Printer.FontSize = 8
Printer.FontBold = False
Printer.Print "Hello World"
Printer.Print: Printer.Print
Printer.NewPage
Printer.EndDoc
```

I had tried to print it and there was no blank lines. Im using a Thermal Printer, so when the code `Printer.EndDoc` it will cut the paper. I need a blank space to make the words "Hello World" are not to close to the end of the paper.

Comment: How do you know you are not getting blank lines?

Comment: I had tried to print it and there was no blank lines. Im using a Thermal Printer, so when the code "Printer.EndDoc" it will cut the paper. I need a blank space to make the word "Hello World" not to close to the end of the paper.

Comment: I don't have a thermal printer to test with. Have you tried simply `Printer.Print " "`?

Comment: Yes I have tried that too. I also have tried this "Printer.Print Spc(2)" and this "Printer.Print Tab(2)".

Comment: Your line with the 2 `Printer.Print` statements should give you 2 blank lines.  If this or the other suggestions don't work then I'm not sure what to try.

Comment: I've just found out. The Printer.Print " " cant be just filled with an empty spc or only a space. So it will look like this ```Printer.Print "A             " ```.

Comment: Printing a blank space doesn’t make sense in the above description, you print a blank space and then a new page, perhaps try changing the x,y coordinates and printing something else.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have written "blank SPACE" but I think you actually mean a blank LINE, is that right?

Comment: The line `Printer.Print: Printer.Print` looks fishy... is that an appropriate use of the colon `:` ?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Yes, it is.

Comment: @GSerg thanks, I couldn't remember if that was OK. I guess its just combining two statements onto a single line IIRC now...

Comment: If all of the above still doesn't get you where you want to be, there may be some oddity with the printer itself so that if no character is printed, the paper doesn't "feed".  You could test this by printing either a `.` or a `_` after the two `.Print` statements and see where they end up...  Also, doin the `.NewPage` without any output may be interfering somehow.  I would experiment with things like that and see, because the 2x `.Print` looks correct on the surface.

Comment: @StayOnTarget Yes, I mean a Blank Line, Printer.Print : Printer.Print was the first. That only works when i put it in middle of the paper.

Comment: @User51 I used 2 different printer and both are new, none of them print a blank line. I am still learning about this program but in my mind ```Printer.Print ""``` should works. 
For now, my code is ```Printer.Print "."```, This what i can do. Although it's a bit disturbing the aesthetics. (Dot in the last line of the paper)

Comment: Maybe try a non-breaking space character instead of a regular space?

Comment: Right.  You could try something such as `Printer.Print Chr(255)`.  I don't recall if `Print` supports Unicode or how to generate a true "nbsp".  There's a chance `255` will do it, because it's sort of the same thing, assuming it doesn't interfere as a control character or some-such.  But tbh, I would have tried exactly what you did.. and, if the `.` gives you what you want, I'd be surprised if `Print: Print: Print " "` didn't.